Google Slides slideshow feature not working in iframe , showing white
Thanks in advance , we were using Google Slides slideshow in iframe and this was working fine but after 10th April 24 , it stopped , its displays white on click of SlideShow button , here we attached link of code pan
https://codepen.io/skumar-C2perform/pen/eYaNzvG
on click of this




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1FdtZ_baKEJ5jq08q7R09ujKA7N5KrXOnE4Fr7APKwZg/edit?usp=sharing" width="550px" height="350px" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-forms allow-presentation allow-modals"
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
</body>
</html>



